# How to configure Android Studio settings for parsing JSON files?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, skin

I am using libgdx skins in a project. Libgdx skins don't use double quotes for keys and values. Android studio shows errors while parsing the skin.json file.

Is there a way to configure Android Studio to ignore the "double quote" check while inspecting a JSON file?

Edit - I want Android Studio to parse the keys and values and the entire file as it normally would, had the "double quotes" been there. That helps in editing the file.

Comment: Put `// @formatter:off` at the top of the file or change the file extension.

Comment: That doesn't work. And i don't want to change the file extension. I want android studio to parse the keys and values and the entire file as it normally would, had the "double quotes" been there. That helps in editing the file.

Comment: In that case I think your options are to write your own parser using Intellij's API, or just use the double quotes even though libgdx doesn't require them.

Comment: Thanks! The former option is beyond my capabilities as of now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Android Studio's Edit->Find->Replace with Regex selected to add double-quotes in my copy:

Find className:

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9\\$]*\.)*[A-Za-z0-9\\$]*)(:)
```

Replace className:

```
"$1"$3
```

Find everything else:

```
([ \t])([A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]*[\.-])*[A-Za-z\.]*)([,:\s])
```

Replace everything else:

```
$1"$2"$4
```